# RegisterClassEx crashes - C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I was working to windows library, I'm new to it, but I'm gettin an error that I googled enough and I don't know what's going on.

Here is my code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WbWindow::st_wind_callback(HWND hWnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM
lParam)
{
 // Code for the callback static function
return 0;
}
WbWMResult WbWindow::Create()
{
// Put in the class values for our window
class_window_instance.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
class_window_instance.lpfnWndProc=WbWindow::st_wind_callback;
class_window_instance.lpszClassName = window_name;
class_window_instance.style = NULL;
class_window_instance.cbClsExtra = 0;
class_window_instance.cbWndExtra = 0;
class_window_instance.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
class_window_instance.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
class_window_instance.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
class_window_instance.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
class_window_instance.hInstance = main_instance;
class_window_instance.lpszMenuName = NULL;

if(!RegisterClassEx(&class_window_instance)){
    MessageBox(0,"There was an error registering the window-classname.","Critical Error!",MB_ICONSTOP | MB_OK);
    return WBE_CLASSREG;
}

window_instance = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_STATICEDGE,window_name,window_title,WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,window_width,window_height,NULL,NULL,main_instance,NULL);
if(window_instance == NULL){
    MessageBox(0,"There was an error creating a window.","Critical Error!",MB_ICONSTOP | MB_OK);
    return WBE_WINCREATION;
}

created = WbTrue;

return WB_SUCCESS;
}
```

The error that I get, it's an error from the debugger: Unhandled exception, it says that it's a problem with a bad pointer at .lpszMenuName, but that works in may examples, I don't know why.

What's going on and how can I fix it?
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, my previous answer was wrong, it was not researched enough, I'll see if I can delete it.

What development environment are you using?
One other thing that came to mind is that the `class_window_instance` structure is not being initialised -- could you try a `memset(&class_window_instance, 0, sizeof(class_window_instance));` at the begining of `WbWindow::Create()`?

Comment: I tried that already.... Sadly is not working with a `= {0}`, or `memset`, or `malloc`...
I'm using visual studio 2010

Comment: I made a small project in VS2010 with your code, I don't get your exception, I got a NULL return from `CreateWindowEx()` because the WindowProc did not have a `return DefWindowProc(hWnd, Message, wParam, lParam);` -- only thing I can think of is to put a breakpoint at the `RegisterClassEx()` call and see if you find anything strange in the `class_window_instance` structure -- sorry!

Comment: Ty... Now, I can know the error I'm having it's coming in another place of the code. I'll check and I'll tell you what the problem was.

Comment: Bingo, The error is the following: `window_name` and `window_title` are char* variables, If I pass that variables to the `.lpszClassName` or into the `CreateWindowEx` I got an error, I don't know why. If I put directly the `"Content"` it works okay. Do you know what's going on there?

Comment: `lpszClassName` and `lpWindowName` are defined as LPCSTR -- do `window_name` and `window_title` have valid string values? where are they defined? [I'm based in Europe, so I may not answer your comments promptly (it's 19:00 here)]

Comment: That was the answer that I was creating... Now that you hit with the problem, I was using char* instead of const char*! Can you post the answer please?

Comment: last comment posted as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lpszClassName` and `lpWindowName` are defined as LPCSTR -- do window_name and window_title have valid string values? where are they defined?

Comment: That's it my friend! Thanks! the window_name and window_title was defined as char*, actually that's not the LPCSTR definition, so I need const char*. Thanks!

Comment: You can pass char* to const char* so this answers nothing so far as I can tell.

Comment: Rarely it was not working with char*.... That's weird, but now It's working good with that change.